# Problems validating session with Zend_Auth

Tags: php, zend-framework

Good evening, I have this code but I need to know if this actually logged but do not make it, that I'm wrong? this scritp not show me any errors: (

```
                  $userDetails = array('foo' => 'bar');
$storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
// set sorage for Zend_Auth
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->setStorage($storage);
// write data to the storage
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($userDetails);
// read data from storage
$c = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
    $result = $c->authenticate($userDetails);
                             echo $this->view->form = var_dump($result);

 if (!$result->isValid()){
     var_dump('FAILURE');
}else{                          
     $this->_helper->redirector('index','index');

}
```

Comment: Do you want to check whether user session exists??

Comment: Yes!.................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check `session` in `Zend` by,

```
if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
    // do user session action
} else {
    // redirect to login page
}
```

To get user info try,

```
$userInfo = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
```